# deserializing a subclassed immutable type (Path) in Python

Tags: python, serialization

Working on a Python (3.6) program that passes around [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) objects, I ended up needing to attach some extra data to the paths. I subclassed Path and got it working ok. However, after put()ing an instance of the Path subclass into a [multiprocessing queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), I ran into an exception (w/ an inscrutable error message...) when trying to get() the object from the queue. Here's a simpler example that just uses pickle to (de)serialize:

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

class BetterPath(type(Path())):
    def __new__(cls, path_str, extra_data):
        res = super().__new__(cls, path_str)
        res.extra_data = extra_data
        return res

subpath = BetterPath('/home/jdoe/file.txt', 'extra_data')
subpath_bytes = pickle.dumps(subpath)
subpath_obj = pickle.loads(subpath_bytes)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    subpath_obj = pickle.loads(subpath_bytes)
TypeError: __new__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Changing the example code to subclass a different immutable type, like int, results in a slightly different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    subpath_obj = pickle.loads(subpath_bytes)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'extra_data'
```

So, how can I modify my code to subclass an immutable type like Path and successfully deserialize an instance object? I tried overriding some of the methods mentioned in the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances), like __getnewargs_ex__(), but to no effect.

Comment: try to print subpath it looks like `BetterPath('/home/jdoe/file.txt')` trouble not in pickle

Comment: Could you clarify? I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Confirmed on python-3.7.3. I have a similar issue with datetime/deepcopy. @BearBrown `print(subpath)` yields "/home/jdoe/file.txt".

Comment: @ederag Thanks for bringing this back up -- found a new solution. (Back in the day, I just switched to a wrapper class containing the separate data alongside the immutable class instance.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, motivated by user ederag's comment, I put some more time in and was able to solve this. The solution:

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

class BetterPath(type(Path())):
    def __new__(cls, *parts, extra_data=None):
        res = super().__new__(cls, *parts)
        res.extra_data = extra_data
        return res

    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), self.parts, self.__dict__, None, None

betterpath = BetterPath('/home/jdoe/file.txt', extra_data='extra_data')
betterpath_bytes = pickle.dumps(betterpath)
betterpath_obj = pickle.loads(betterpath_bytes)
```

The bottom line is that `__getnewargs__()`/`__getnewargs_ex__()` don't come into play at all. (Maybe they do work for non-immutable classes, ones that use `__init__()`?) The important method is [`__reduce__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html?highlight=__reduce__#object.__reduce__). The description in pickle's documentation is sufficient:

- 1st arg is the callable
- 2nd arg is the tuple of args that will be passed to the callable
- 3rd arg is the dict of attributes that will be passed to `__setstate__()`

The new `parts` variable and unpacking operations are incidental -- I only added those after I noticed the Path/PosixPath/etc classes actually take a tuple of path parts as args. (Passing in a single path str is sort of a special case.) Similarly, changing `extra_data` to a keyword argument was only due to the `parts` change -- either `extra_data` has to be a keyword, or passed in as the 1st argument and handled separately from the `parts` arguments.